# Why do modern C/C++ compilers put aditional unused data into the output binaries?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, llvm, portable-executable

I'm a low-level developer and a reverse-engineer. While investigating malware and software compiled using different compilers such as LLVM GCC/G++ for windows I found out that modern compilers put additional unused sections to the compiled binary, increasing it's size a lot. Example:

```
gcc -fPIC -march=native -O3 cleaner.c
strip a.exe
```

In the output binary we see theese sections, while in reality only .data and .text are really used by the program. Because of that, size of the program is about 40 kb.

[Sections preview for GCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltA3L.png)

But if we compile the same program with TCC (Tiny C Compiler) we get a binary that works exactly the same, but it's size is just 2.5 kb and it doesn't have those additional sections.

```
tcc.exe -lpsapi cleaner.c
```

[Sections preview for TCC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsIGn.png)

So the question is - why are modern compilers so bloated and is it possible to make the LLVM GCC/G++ compiler to stop creating those?

By compiling a simple binary I expect it to have only .text and .data sections, but it also has .rdata, .tls, .reloc and other ones, which increase the size of the executable but aren't really used in the program itself.

UPDATE In the comments people say that those sections are really important and used, but if you look into them using IDA or a simple hex editor you'll a see a lot of zero bytes and other useless stuff that takes a LOT of size ( the actual code is located in .text, and static data is located in .data)

[HEX dump of a compiled executable section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2VVu.png)

Comment: "_but aren't really used in the program itself._": They are all used when running the program, except `.buildid` which is there to help e.g. matching core files. They all have their purpose.

Comment: Btw. if you want a _small_ executable you should use `-Os`, not `-O3`. `-O3` intentionally enables optimizations that may increase the binary size, sometimes significantly, trading it for runtime performance.